# Regex to identify word "PRIMARY KEY" in .sql file

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to build regex to find word PRIMARY KEY in .sql file.... Like there is a file which contains several Create table {} scripts. I just want to check if the primary key is set or not while creating the table

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE
{
.....
.....
PRIMARY KEY
...
}
CREATE TABLE
{
.....
.....
...
}
CREATE TABLE
{
.....
.....
PRIMARY KEY
...
}
```

here the second create table does not conatin primary key..
So i want to build regex for finding wheter primary key is defined or not...
I am scning file using ReadToEnd function from .net and then want to appy regex on it for match..

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What is your goal at the end of the day? eg: Are you validating `CREATE TABLE` statements, to error-out if no PRIMARY KEY is defined? Trying to extract some useful data for later? something else?

Comment: Yes Actually i am trying to raise an error if no PRIMARY KEY is defined in create table... So if in any CREATE TABLE block if the primary is not define it should be an error...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know .net, but I think this can't be done by only using a single regex.
I would go trough the file, checking with one regex if a new CREATE TABLE {  starts, and if yes, check if there is a PRIMARY KEY before the next CREATE TABLE {.

Comment: And you don't need a regex for that, a simple substring match is enough.

Comment: Actually i am looking for regex match as i am doing it throught my application.. so the regex for same will be helpful..

Comment: Mmh Well, the regex to match PRIMARY KEY and CREATE TABLE isn't so hard. Here: .*PRIMARY.KEY.* This matches PRIMARY KEY anywhere in a line and .*CREATE.TABLE.*  same here. But I don't think that will be enough to get this working properly.